# VueJS and Firebase Storage: How to wait until image done uploading before submitting URI to database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2, firebase-storage

I have a comment system I built that allows a user to add an image along with their comment.
I am trying to wait until an image upload is finished before adding a comment to firestore, but my attempt is not working. I have a method named `photoUpload()` that uploads the image to firebase storage. That method contains an `uploadTask` listener for progress details. However, my comment is being added to the database before the image is done uploading.

How to delay and wait until it's finished before submitting the comment?

Here's my code:

> data function:

```
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
      image: null,
      overlayShow: false,
      progress: 0,
      downloadUrl: null
    }
  },
```

> Here is my image upload task:

```
photoUpload() {
  this.filename = uuidv4()
  const storageRef = this.$fireStorage.ref()
  this.photoRef = storageRef.child(
    `photos/${this.userProfile.uid}/commentPhotos/${this.filename}`
  )
  // uploads string data to this reference's location
  const uploadTask = this.photoRef.putString(this.image, 'data_url')

  // set the callbacks for each event
  const next = (uploadTaskSnapshot) => {
    this.progress =
      (uploadTaskSnapshot.bytesTransferred /
        uploadTaskSnapshot.totalBytes) *
      100
    console.log('Upload is ' + this.progress + '% done')
  }
  const error = (error) => {
    ...snijp...
  }
const complete = async () => {
    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    this.downloadUrl = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
  }
  // listens for events on this task
  uploadTask.on(
    // 3 callbacks available for each event
    this.$fireStorageObj.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    {
      next,
      error,
      complete
    }
  )
}
```

> To add a comment to firestore, I run this method:

```
async addComment() {
  this.overlayShow = true
  if (this.hasImage) {
    this.photoUpload() // <---------I need to wait on this to finish!
  }
  try {
    console.log(this.downloadUrl) //<-----this is returning null even after image is uploaded
    // create comment
    const docRef = this.$fireStore.collection('comments').doc()
    await docRef.set({
      createdAt: this.$fireStoreObj.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      id: docRef.id,
      content: this.text,
      attachment: this.downloadUrl, //<---- because photo upload is not finished, this gets null
    })
    console.log('comment added!')
    // update comment count on photo doc
    await this.$fireStore
      .collection('photos')
      .doc(this.photo.id)
      .set(
        {
          comments: this.$fireStoreObj.FieldValue.increment(1)
        },
        { merge: true }
      )
    this.text = ''
    this.downloadUrl = null
    this.clearImage()
    this.overlayShow = false
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding new comment', error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `uploadComplete` async, and return a promise that resolves only after the upload is complete and the download URL is available.  Since all of its work is asynchronous, you must build a way for the caller to know that, otherwise the function will return immediately before anything is complete.

It might be easier if you also await the await the uploadTask (it acts like a promise) to know when it's complete, instead of using the callbacks.

Comment: OK, I am going to have to study this...pretty complex but I will slowly but surely see if I can do this....